# SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by

i have two pointages and chantiers table between them belongsTo relationship,
I want to display the chantiers name and the sum of sold for each chantier I tried this function, but it gives me error

```
$dataP = DB::table('chantiers')
         ->leftJoin('pointages','pointages.chantier_id','chantiers.id')
          ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(pointages.sold),0) as sold,chantiers.chantier')
          ->groupBy('pointages.chantier_id')
          ->get();
```

**pointages table**

[image]

**chantiers table**

[image]

**error**
[image]

Comment: you'll need to also select that `pointages.chantier_id` if you want to group on it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thx for answer I try but it even gives me error

Comment: please prove that claim by updating your post with the new query and new error. Also, please do _not_ screenshot the error: copy-paste the text and either code-format it, or make it a quote.

Answer (score 1):

Your mysql version is 5.7+, so check this [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

> MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list

### Solution 1:

Check the config/database.php, if your mysql configuration `strict => true`, you need to disabled the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, add `modes` like this:

```php
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            ...
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'modes' => [
                //'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
                'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
                'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
                'NO_ZERO_DATE',
                'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
                'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
                'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
           ],
        ],
```

PS: set `strict => false` can work too, but disabling it  make your app unsecured.

### Solution 2:

Use [ANY_VALUE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value):

> This function is useful for GROUP BY queries when the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled, for cases when MySQL rejects a query that you know is valid for reasons that MySQL cannot determine. The function return value and type are the same as the return value and type of its argument, but the function result is not checked for the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode.

```php
$dataP = DB::table('chantiers')
         ->leftJoin('pointages','pointages.chantier_id','chantiers.id')
          ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(pointages.sold),0) AS sold, ANY_VALUE(chantiers.chantier) AS chantier, pointages.chantier_id')
          ->groupBy('pointages.chantier_id')
          ->get();
```

PS: `ANY_VALUE` does not exist on **MariaDB**.

Answer (score 0):

> Group by only possible on select field

As per your above query, you don't add group by field in the select field that why Laravel gave you the error.

So can you please try following which will work for you

```
$dataP = DB::table('chantiers')
         ->leftJoin('pointages','pointages.chantier_id','chantiers.id')
          ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(pointages.sold),0) as sold,chantiers.chantier,pointages.chantier_id')
          ->groupBy('pointages.chantier_id')
          ->get();
```

Hope you get your require answer

Answer (score 0):

run this command in database sql

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode='';
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.